# Stop clipping ggsurvplot risk table text while annotating right-side of survival graph (long labels)

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

I want to specify the end time in my ggsurvplot, annotating the ends of the survival curves as shown below. But this leads to a truncation of the rightmost text in number-at-risk table. See code and output graphic below. Note that in the graphic, the rightmost values are 20 and 21, but all you see is 2 and 2.

If I increase the right-side x-axis limit (replace `xlim=c(-50, time_cutoff)` with `xlim=c(-50, time_cutoff+50)`), the risk table text is not clipped, but the survival curves are also plotted out to time_cutoff+50 and the labels I show to the right of the survival curve do not align with the ends of the survival curves.\

If I set clip='off' for just the risk table, I get extra values printed past the xlim cutoff.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

# Customized survival curves
my_plot = ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung,
 # Add p-value and tervals
 risk.table = TRUE,
 tables.height = 0.2,
 break.x.by=100,
 ggtheme = theme_bw() # Change ggplot2 theme              
)

time_cutoff = 400
xticks = c(0, 100, 200, 300, 400)

survs = summary(fit, times=time_cutoff)$surv
labels = paste(round(survs*100), '% this label is really long', sep='')
  
my_plot$plot <- my_plot$plot + 
                coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1), xlim = c(-50,time_cutoff), clip = 'on', expand=FALSE) +
                scale_x_continuous(name=NULL, breaks = xticks) +
                scale_y_continuous(name=NULL, sec.axis=sec_axis(~., name=NULL, breaks = survs, labels= labels))  +
                theme(
                  panel.border = element_blank(),
                  axis.line.y.left = element_line(color = 'black'),
                  axis.line.x.bottom = element_line(color = 'black'),
                )

table_ylim = ggplot_build(my_plot$table)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range
my_plot$table <- my_plot$table + 
                coord_cartesian(ylim=table_ylim, xlim = c(-50,time_cutoff), clip = 'on', expand=FALSE) +
                scale_x_continuous(name=NULL, breaks = xticks) +
                theme(panel.border = element_blank())
library(patchwork)
(my_plot$plot / my_plot$table) + plot_layout(heights = c(3,1))
```

[image]
Now with clip='off' for just the risk table:
[image]

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74789787) similar question with short labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leave clipping off, but remove the labels in the table's layer data when time > 400:

```r
my_plot$table$layer[[1]]$data$llabels[
  my_plot$table$layer[[1]]$data$time > 400] <- NA
  
(my_plot$plot / my_plot$table) + plot_layout(heights = c(3,1))
```

[image]